# Xcode for MAC dev: How to have a keybinding for menu item?

Tags: c, xcode, macos

I'm newish to Xcode and Mac development. I'm trying to make it so that a menu item can be activated by a keyboard shortcut (such as CMD+S is shortcut for save in many programs.)

How can I do this?

PS: I'd also like for this shortcut to be up in the menu item. I assume that's done automatically in the programming but if not I'd like help with that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just double-click on the keyboard shortcut in the .xib and type whatever key combination you want.  Here's an example of an empty project that I changed the "save" key shortcut to <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]